# How to create a runnable jar which has a dependency

Tags: java, gradle

This is my first experiment with Gradle 2.3, and it seems like it should be so simple I'm missing something obvious, but I can't figure it out.  Nothing jumps out at me from the documentation, and I've tried several things having googled for it but none of them make any difference.

I have a simple project which writes to and then reads back some info from a MongoDB database.  It's working fine; I can execute it:

- via `gradle run` on the command line
- from within Eclipse Luna
- via a jar file generated from Eclipse, which I can run via the `java` command

However, I just cannot produce a runnable jar file from Gradle itself.  My build.gradle file consists of:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'com.poldie.quicktest.HelloWorld'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.poldie.quicktest.HelloWorld'
    }

    baseName = 'my-handy-jar'

}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.7.0.RELEASE'
}
```

And when I examine my-handy.jar.jar I see:

```
$ jar tf my-handy-jar.jar 
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/
com/poldie/
com/poldie/quicktest/
com/poldie/quicktest/Person.class
com/poldie/quicktest/HelloWorld.class
```

And trying to run it gives me:

```
$ java -jar my-handy-jar.jar 
    Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
```

Obviously the jar file produced by Eclipse is a lot bigger, containing the dependencies, and works.  How do I achieve this with Gradle?

(Using `gradle build` to create the jar worked on a simpler version of my project before I added the MongoDB dependency)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a Class-path entry to the manifest listing the jars this one depends on, as relative URLs relative to the location of this .jar file. Typically the other .jar files will be in the same directory, or a lib/ subdirectory.

Comment: 1) What's the best way of knowing what all the .jar files represented by spring-data-mongodb. I can jar tf the jar produced by Eclipse; is there a better way?  2) Gradle would have downloaded them for me at some point - or perhaps they were downloaded when I installed the Spring Tool Suite into Eclipse - so I'm not sure where they are.

Comment: Cannot help with that. I know nothing about Gradle.

Comment: Well, you've helped me along my quest, so thanks anyway!

Comment: Look in your user directory for files in `C:\Users\<User>\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1` for files. I use `LibGDX` which has a Gradle based setup, and that's where everything is at for me.

Comment: @CoderMusgrove I'm using linux, but i can see some files in the corresponding location (a jar, sources.jar and a .pom).  I've noticed that I get a .tar file containing the jars in the build/distributions folder, so i've copied them elsewhere and am currently trying to include them in the classpath, albeit unsuccessfully.  Is what I'm doing unusual?  Why wouldn't Gradle create a runnable .jar out of the box?

Comment: I don't know about that. I use eclipse for my programming and gradle integration. The only difference I see between my gradle build file and yours is I have these `project(...)` mappings, (I have a `project(":core")` and `project(":desktop")`). Sorry, I can't help you past that.